Do we need the algebraic structure of $\Bbb R$ to do (algebraic) topology?
Motivation: The Borsuk-Ulam theorem is stated in terms of the antipodal map $x\mapsto-x$, but self-homeomorphisms of the sphere can turn many different maps into $-$, so the theorem should hold if we replace negation with any such map. (Maybe these are the continuous involutions of degree $1$ or something; Wikipedia claims that any involution works.)
Generalizing the theorem in this way doesn't completely remove its dependence on the algebraic structure of $\Bbb R$, because the sphere itself is defined algebraically as the locus of $|x|=1$. This seems like just a convenience, though, since we could define the sphere in other ways (e.g. recursively by gluing two cones on a lower-dimensional sphere).
It seems like, with some work, we could state and prove versions of Borsuk-Ulam and similar fixed-point theorems using a "purely topological" version of $\Bbb R$ on which we avoid imposing any algebraic structure. This approach has some aesthetic appeal to me, even though I realize the resulting theorems are no more useful than the standard versions.
How much of topology (I guess I mean the "nice" parts: topology of manifolds / algebraic topology?) can be developed in this way? Has it been done? Are there certain proofs and/or definitions that are hard to reformulate?
How and why does the "rigid" algebraic structure of $\Bbb R$ help us do "stretchy" topology?

Somewhat relevant discussion on MathOverflow about the role of the unit interval in defining fundamental groups: https://mathoverflow.net/q/92206/285346

'How and why does the "rigid" algebraic structure of $\mathbb{R}$ help us do "stretchy" topology?' There's a rather obvious (partial) answer to this: (a) algebraic topology is about continuous maps (in particular, "stretchiness" is really just the existence of certain continuous maps called "homotopies") (b) defining continuous maps on general spaces is difficult  (c) the algebraic structure on $\mathbb{R}$ helps to remedy this, because it is compatible with the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore can be used to define continuous maps.

There are settings in algebraic topology in particular that rely much less on this than the "basic" stuff: The first obvious candidate to look at is model categories, because a model category captures an abstract notion of homotopy theory independent of the point-set details of topology and of $\mathbb{R}$. The second is to take a walk through the lofty land of spectra, in particular the modern, $\infty$-categorial setting, where most things are done "coordinate-free," and see what you can bring down to earth (in particular, you'll learn how to avoid things like "barycentric subdivision").

On that note, what do you mean by "algebraic structure?" Just the field operations on $\mathbb{R}$ or the order as well? Without the order, I imagine things will be quite difficult.

You can, although some arguments will become unnecessarily painful. You would also loose connections to other parts of mathematics such as differential topology, differential geometry, analysis, algebra... What would be the point? If all you care about is the formulation of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem using fixed-point free involutions on spheres (BTW, defining a "sphere" without algebra will be painful as well!), you should ask a separate question. I am voting to close since it is really unclear what are you after.

Thanks, all these comments are enlightening. I'll try proving this form of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem to see where the difficulties are and will check out model categories. I'm content to have this question closed for lack of focus.
